# Mapping an ACI-instance to a Reserved IP on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances

Are there any best practices on continuous deployment to an Azure Container Instance so that it keeps the public IP?  Or mapping an Azure Reserved IP to a dynamic IP that the ACI gets bound to at deployment?

Answer (score 6):

Currently, your best bet is to create a DNS A record for the app and remap it to the new IP when you create a new container. However, we are working on enabling you to simply update the container and keep the IP.

**Update:** You can now request a DNS entry for your ACI container in the Microsoft-managed azurecontainer.io domain using the `dns-name-label` switch in the az cli. You can keep this DNS stable across updates.

```
az container create -n helloworld --image microsoft/aci-helloworld /
    -g myResourceGroup --dns-name-label mycontainer
```

Comment: Could you post here once that is available on ACI?

Comment: Sure, will do. The first thing we're going to enable is the ability to create a DNS record in our domain (azurecontainer.io) that can be stable across updates. That should be available in the API in the next month or so.

Comment: This is now available and I have updated my answer above.

Comment: But can I assign a reserved IP to my container? this is a requirements in my case. Can I do this with Azure Function? AKS?

Comment: This is only for dns. Our use case also require direct communication with a static reserved IP address. Is this at all possible with container instances?