# Can I assign a reserved IP to Azure Container Instances (ACI)?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

ok, I have a requirement from third-part to run a workload from a specific IP (so they can white-list it). Can I assign a reserved IP to my ACI container?

Comment: Here is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199064/mapping-an-aci-instance-to-a-reserved-ip-on-azure?rq=1) you could refer to.

Comment: That's not my question in that thread. I need to assign a reserved IP to ACI container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### UPDATE

### You can now assign a private IP address by joining your container group to a VNET! Check out details at https://aka.ms/aci/vnet.

You cannot assign a private IP address to a container group today. We are enabling assignment of private IP addresses to container groups later this year so you can join a container group to a new or existing private VNET.

Note ACI also does not guarantee a static IP address for a container group, the link provided by Joey details how to setup a DNS name label to utilize a reliable endpoint though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please provide this functionality at least for a group. There are many use cases when the services must operate from a static public IP. Because consumers or providers just whitelist IP's.

Comment: We absolutely agree, we're working on that functionality as well so support the exact whitelisting scenario you describe. We're making progress and should have updates on increased networking capability this year. Thanks for your patience and feedback, we'll make it happen.

Comment: curious if there's a feature link to check progress?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Chris - you can now join a VNET with Linux containers in ACI. We're still closing down the static IP capability, should have better updates by end of 2018!

Comment: jluk thank you for the information. I would like to mention that for mine organization this static IP capability is also a very important functionality. We build our software based on Docker containers and we have a lot of cases where our integrations required IP whitelists.

Comment: @jluk the VNET doc page suggests this only works for private IP addresses, which aren't useful in the scenario described in the question (if I'm understanding this correctly). Is there any update on how to have a static public IP address for an ACI group?

Comment: @jluk Is there any update on this? Any channel I can follow regarding announcements? Static IP really is an important feature.

Comment: can we assign static private IP? I deploy container in VNET and its working but it's automaticaly assign the private ip address from subnet. I'm using smtp4dev and need static private ip address ? is there any workaround ?